# The specified type member "" is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linq, entity-framework

I'm having a problem with LINQ

```
var operations = (from c in dCAPPEntities.CIC_OPERAZIONI
                                where c.CD_CIC_PRODUZIONE == 15835 && !(from s in dCAPPEntities.CIC_SEQUENCE where s.CD_CIC_PRODUZIONE==15835 select s.CD_CIC_OPERAZIONE).Contains(c.CD_CIC_OPERAZIONI) select new { c }).GroupBy(i=>i.c.CD_CIC_OPERAZIONI, i=> new Alternative1{ State=0, Iden=i.c.Iden});
```

when I execute this query I get the following error:
The specified type member 'Iden' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

if I write Iden="" in the query it works, so I have no idea why I got the error.

I also add the code of some classes I used:

```
public interface IAlternative
{
    string Iden { get; }

    int State { get; set; }

}
```

partial class that extends the table

```
 public partial class CIC_OPERAZIONI : IAlternative
{
public string Iden
    {
        get
        {
            return AFCDOPER + "\r" + AFDSOPER;
        }
    }

    private int _state = 0;
    public int State
    {
        get { return _state; }
        set
        {
            _state = value;
        }
    }
}
```

and the last class i think can be useful to understand the problem

```
public class Alternative1 : INotifyPropertyChanged, IAlternative
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #region IAlternative Members

    public string Iden { get; set; }


    public int State { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c` is a `CIC_OPERAZIONI`. `CIC_OPERAZIONI.Iden` is not an entity member or navigation property, it's a computed property with a value that depends on other properties. EF doesn't support that: your query doesn't actually end up creating `CIC_OPERAZIONI` objects, so there is no way to have `CIC_OPERAZIONI` member functions or properties get called. Depending on the definition of the other properties, it may or may not work if you expand it inline:

```
[...].GroupBy(
    i=> i.c.CD_CIC_OPERAZIONI,
    i=> new Alternative1
        {
            State = 0,
            Iden = i.c.AFCDOPER + "\r" + i.c.AFDSOPER
        })
```

If it doesn't work, it's probably because `AFCDOPER` or `AFDSOPER` isn't an entity member either, and you need to do the same with those other properties.

Comment: in this case I got another error, this tyoe is about casting: Unable to cast the type 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types. but I can't use ToString in a LINQ expression.

Comment: and If I leave only the string property, the query is executed correctly, but Iden is always set to NULL

Comment: I don't see anything about decimal properties in your question. What properties is that about? In order for `AFCDOPER + "\r" + AFDSOPER` to work in C#, both `AFCDOPER` and `AFDSOPER` must be string properties, right?

Comment: ok let's work only with AFDSOPER (string), in this case the query is correct, but Iden is always null.... seems that I can't reach the CIC_OPERAZIONI properties

Comment: Oh, I forgot, there is a subtle difference between how EF sees it and how C# sees it: EF translates it to SQL, and SQL makes `table.AFCDOPER + '\r' + table.AFDSOPER` evaluate to `NULL` if either `table.AFCDOPER` or `table.AFDSOPER` is `NULL`. If that is the case, you could try `(i.c.AFCDOPER ?? "") + "\r" + (i.c.AFDSOPER ?? "")` instead.

Comment: no that is not the problem... neither one of the two properties is NULL.

Comment: In that case, I fear there isn't enough information for me to be able to help right now. It *should* work, and I'll see if I can create a sample (later) that shows a case where it works, which you can then adapt to your situation.

Comment: thank you, I'm tryng to solve it or to use some other properties